# Writing new functions into progmem after main program is burned

Tags: bootloader

I've been experimenting with writing very basic operating system-like programs on the Arduino, and so far I have been running user-defined programs on a small virtual machine I wrote.  This has been an interesting experience, but the VM runs on an assembly-like language and not C.

I want to be able to do something more.  I would like to be able to write a core OS, and then install new programs, written in C.  The core OS would get user input for which program to run, and then jump to that program.

Now, I know that I can do this trivially by writing the OS along with all of the programs into a single sketch. The programs are then just functions, and the OS just calls those functions.  However, I want to do this with functions I've written *after* I've burned the main OS.

From what I can tell, this is just a bootloader with additional user functionality.  However, I don't think that's quite right for two reasons:

First, I keep hearing that you can't write to progmem at runtime.  But isn't that what a bootloader does?  Which is correct?

Second, once a user program ends, I should return to the OS.  As far as I understand it, on the ATMega, once the main function terminates it jumps into a no-operation function and that's that.  I'd need it to jump back to the bootloader and continue the bootloader's operation.  Is that even possible?

Comment: If this is what you want to do you have chosen the wrong MCU.  Find something that can run from RAM, even if a bit inefficiently - competing ARM Cortex MCUs typically can.  Also understand that this "C" code you speak of gets compiled to machine instructions before it runs - you can compile C to instructions for a virtual machine, too.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and I've got an M0 that I can play around with.  However, I am using the AVR for a few reasons.  First, I'm familiar with it.  Second, because it doesn't just automatically have facilities to run like this I have to create them all myself.  My goal with these projects is to learn HOW those facilities are developed, not to get anything useful out of them.  So I chose a limited chip and made my own workarounds so that I understand how the more advanced chips do it all natively.

Comment: Your workaround might be an interesting puzzle, but it's not really how more capable chips would do it at all, but rather a workaround for the anachronistic limitations of the avr.

Comment: [Seems you can fool the protection](https://hackaday.com/2015/07/03/arduinos-and-other-avrs-write-to-own-flash/)

Comment: @ChrisStratton: yes, you're right.  But doing it on my own means I get to make my own file system, loader style thing etc.  However, I'm actually probably going to just avoid it all and use a Cortex now that I know they CAN execute from RAM.  I guess it pays to do your homework

Comment: @Gerben nothing is being "fooled" but only delegated.  Delegating flash writing to a bit of code stored in a place where that is permissible is an old technique, for example on some MCU's you need a stub running from RAM to actually commit the flash writes.  In that case it's merely delegating from one part of flash to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, I keep hearing that you can't write to progmem at runtime. But
>   isn't that what a bootloader does?

Indeed. My understanding is that *non-bootloader code* cannot write to
the Flash, except on the smallest AVRs. You may need to check the
datasheet of your target MCU.

> Second, once a user program ends, I should return to the OS.

You could require for the user programs to be linked against a library
you provide. Just implement `void exit(int status)` in that library and
it will automatically override the version from avr-libc.

Comment: Yes, a quick datasheet dive reveals the following:  There are three sections in flash.  Boot is a special section where code running can actively modify progmem.  No-Read-While-Write is a section that does not allow for code to run while it is being updated (the CPU is halted).  Read-While-Write does allow for code to run while it is being updated, BUT the code that runs can only run from the NRWW section.  So it looks like I can write the OS to have an "installer" in BOOT, kernelspace in NRWW, and userspace in RWW.